# Selecionar uma tabela Mysql dentro de um arquivo PHP sem refresh

Tags: php, mysql, select

Selecionar dados do banco Mysql dentro de um arquivo PHP sem refresh.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
// Essa select abaixo tem que buscar a cada 5 segundos sem atualizar a página
$selecionaTabela = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nomeTabela")or die(mysql_error());
// Fecha Select

$verifica = mysql_num_rows($selecionaTabela);
if($verifica >= 1){
   echo "Vai exibir os conteúdos aqui...";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você deveria usar Javascript (AJAX) pra exibir os dados sem ter que recarregar a página principal. Sugiro usar a biblioteca jQuery para facilitar a interação das requisições AJAX.

1) Separe o arquivo que contém a query e que monta a exibição dos dados
`ajax.php`

```
<?php
// Essa select abaixo tem que buscar a cada 5 segundos sem atualizar a página
$selecionaTabela = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nomeTabela")or die(mysql_error());
// Fecha Select

$verifica = mysql_num_rows($selecionaTabela);
if($verifica >= 1){
   $dados = mysql_fetch_array($selecionaTabela);
   print_r($dados);
}
```

2) No arquivo principal, o qual você quer mostrar os dados, faça a requisição AJAX para o arquivo que contém a query (ajax.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exibe dados</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //chama a função atualizaDados daqui à 5000ms (5s)
            window.setTimeout(atualizaDados, 5000);
            function atualizaDados() {
                //carrega o conteúdo do arquivo "ajax.php" para dentro da div#exibeDados
                $("#exibeDados").load('ajax.php');
                //para perpetuar a chamada da função sempre a cada 5s
                window.setTimeout(atualizaDados, 5000);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

    <body>
        <div id="exibeDados">
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fiz do jeitinho que você colocou acima, mas no navegador Chrome as imagens ficam piscando! E no Firefox Mozilla não pisca. Segue o link que fiz: http://wesleyk.com.br/timeline.php

Comment: Imagino que "pisca" pois o código sobrescreve o conteúdo da `<div>` com novas tags `<img>`, fazendo que o `src` delas sejam carregados todas as vezes que são inseridas. Imagino que no Mozilla não aparenta "piscar" pois as imagens já estão armazenadas em cache, sendo imperceptível o carregamento.

Comment: Entendi, é que estou fazendo uma timeline, e seria igual a do facebook, quando houver novos conteúdos vai aparecer sem refresh na página