# Formulário dinâmico usando Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um formulário, onde serão lançado dos dados do cabeçalho e itens. Eu sei usar a Tab do Bootstrap, mas nos itens gostaria de chamar uma outra página para que fique fácil fazer o lançamento dos itens e não de *refresh* na janela inteira.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#dados" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Dados</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'cadastros/entradas/teste'; ?> " role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Itens</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pagamento" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pagamento</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane active"  id="itens">
</div>
```

Comment: Veja se isto te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20779/7261

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer fazer uma chamada de uma página via ajax ao clicar em uma das tab, é isso?

Se for, da uma olhada aqui : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
});
```

Existe n coisas que você pode fazer, uma delas é colocar um id para o item que quer fazer isso e dai fazer a chamada somente para esse item, vai do que precisar mesmo!

por exemplo, no

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'cadastros/entradas/teste'; ?> " role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="meu_item_teste">Itens</a></li>
```

e no js

```
$('a#meu_item_teste').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // aqui vem toda brincadeira do ajax
});
```