# Atualizar informações em tempo real javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber alguma forma de atualizar informações de uma determinada pagina, ou seja se eu modificar algum arquivo, atualizar em tempo real sem que seja necessário dar refresh na página com javascript.

Supomos que mudo uma informação em um arquivo de uma página, a página muda automaticamente sem dar refresh nem atualização.

Obrigado

Comment: Boa tarde, não é duplicado, pois o meu caso, é se altero uma coisa no banco  de dados a página também vai mudar.

Comment: Boa tarde, Gonçalo a solução é ajax, independente de ter banco de dados ou não, *acredito eu*, então basta você fazer o teu php conectar no banco, mas a atualização é via ajax. Se você não sabe usar php+mysql, então a questão é outra. O ajax esta no front-end e o banco de dados no backend. ajax é front-end do php, o php é back-end do ajax, php é front-end do banco de dados (mysql por exemplo) e o mysql é backend do php (hoje em dia os termos são fortemente usados pra definir html+css+js como front-end e php+mysql como backend, no entanto mysql geralmente esta em uma camada mais profunda).

Comment: ...Continuando, não sei se os termos que citei aqui estão corretos, mas acredito ser isto, então a tua duvida ou é atualizar a página ou é aprender a usar mysql (ou postgresql) com php.

Comment: Boa Tarde, Eu sei usar php + mysql contudo tenho conhecidos muito baixos de ajax, daí vir a minha dúvida.

Comment: Então o problema é com ajax e acredito que você tenha entendido que o ajax não vai afetar o mysql, que vai trabalhar o mysql é o php, então o teu problema é apenas como usar ajax, a unica coisa que o ajax faz é uma requisição sem precisar página e salva a resposta em uma variavel javascript, acredito que a outra pergunta lhe ajude. Se ainda não estiver claro nela, tente estas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20779/selecionar-uma-tabela-mysql-dentro-de-um-arquivo-php-sem-refresh e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4450/navegação-sem-refresh