# Atualizar DIV em Tempo Real

Tags: javascript, ajax

Gostaria de atualizar apenas uma div de um site, sem atualizar o site todo e que essa div fosse atualiza de 0.1 segundos a cada 0.1 segundos, e que por exemplo não fosse precisar dar refresh ou reentrar no site.

Basicamente gostava de fazer uma alteração no meu servidor, e não ter que tar a atualizar o site para ver essa alteração, mas queria q isso acontece em apenas 1 div do meu site.

Como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Relacionado: [Atualizar informações em tempo real javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91492/atualizar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-tempo-real-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: Não é duplicata, no caso era com php, agora quero com javascript/ajax

Comment: Mas é duplicada da segunda que postei. Que é até sua mesmo a pergunta.

Comment: Gonçalo não duplique perguntas sem necessidade, não é a primeira vez que você faz isso, criar duplicatas só prejudica a comunidade em vários fatores, fora que existem outros meios de tornar a sua pergunta mais evidente, **leia isto**: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3966/3635 - Entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
   <script>
   var nomedafuncao = function () {
  $('#iddadiv').load('paginaquequercarregar.php?_=' + new Date().getTime());
  };
   setInterval(nomedafuncao, 1000); // <- 1000 tempo em milisegundos = 1 segundo
   </script>
```

outra opcao e usar long pooling

Comment: Não ta a funcionar a div não atualiza.

Comment: seria bom postar seu codigo para analizar melhor, vc esta linkando o jquery?